# how can i make the border red when the user in same page css

Tags: html, css

I have one page sign up with two choice email / phone, when user click on phone button to sign up i want the border still red i make it hover when mouse over it but i don't know how to make when in same page the border be red also .

[image]

```css
.EPbutton{
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
width: 130px;
height: 20px;
margin-top: 12px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.EPbutton:hover{
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
color:red;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: please put your html code also

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: input:focus
{
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
color:red;
cursor: pointer;
}

Answer (score 0):

`:focus`

```
.EPbutton:focus {
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
color:red;
cursor: pointer;
}
```